# this particular line of code is far away from my understanding,what does this do?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
if (i + j) % 8 in [1, 5]:
```

what does this line of code mean and how will it execute?

```
for i in range(8):
    for j in range(16):
        if (i + j) % 8 in [1, 5]:
            print('/', end = '')
```

Comment: `%` is a modulo operator, so if the remainer of the division of `(i+j)/8` is either 1 or 5, the `print()` function is executed.

Comment: Have you done the official Python tutorial, and have you searched the doc for the various existing operators ?

Comment: @ilja in python3, `print()` is a function, not a statement.

Comment: @bruno desthuilliers, of course, you are right :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It checks if `i+j` modulo 8 is 1 or 5.

- `(i+j)` returns its sum (obviously)
- `% 8` returns [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) 8. For example: `8 % 8 == 0, 9 % 8 == 1, 10 % 8 == 2` etc
- `in [1, 5]` checks if `(i + j) % 8` result can be found in list `[1, 5]` - if it equals to 1 or it equals to 5

Here is the official Python documentation [about modulo](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=modulo#binary-arithmetic-operations) operator:

> The % (modulo) operator yields the remainder from the division of the first argument by the second. The numeric arguments are first converted to a common type. A zero right argument raises the ZeroDivisionError exception. The arguments may be floating point numbers, e.g., 3.14%0.7 equals 0.34 (since 3.14 equals 4*0.7 + 0.34.) The modulo operator always yields a result with the same sign as its second operand (or zero); the absolute value of the result is strictly smaller than the absolute value of the second operand [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

Here is official Python documentation [about "in"](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=modulo#membership-test-operations) operator:

> The operators in and not in test for membership. x in s evaluates to True if x is a member of s, and False otherwise. x not in s returns the negation of x in s. All built-in sequences and set types support this as well as dictionary, for which in tests whether the dictionary has a given key. For container types such as list, tuple, set, frozenset, dict, or collections.deque, the expression x in y is equivalent to any(x is e or x == e for e in y).
>
> For the string and bytes types, x in y is True if and only if x is a substring of y. An equivalent test is y.find(x) != -1. Empty strings are always considered to be a substring of any other string, so "" in "abc" will return True.

Comment: i.e. `i+j` is one of `1, 5, 9, 13, 17, 21`. great answer!

Answer (score 1):

`in` operator (membership operator) : The ‘in’ operator is used to check if a value exists in a sequence or not. It evaluates to true if it finds a value in the specified sequence and false otherwise.

% operator is used for modulo division.

Here `(i+j)%8` returns the value from 0 to 7, as it is modulo division.

But in the code the result of modulo division is cheked in the list `[1,5]`, weather it is present in it or not.

If it is present in the list, we are executing the statement in the if condition else going for next iteration of loop.